# Number of words of fixed length, starting with A and ending with B, without double letter

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So I have a graph-related problem, where I need to determine **the number of paths** of length $L$ from Node $N_A$ to node $N_B$, in a **complete graph** containing $N$ nodes. Nodes $N_A$ and $N_B$ can point to the same node.

An example application of this problem is finding the number of words of length $L$, starting with letter `A` and ending with letter `B` (the actual letters do not matter), and the graph is simply an alphabet of size $N$. Because it is a complete graph, no double letters are allowed, so words like `AACB` or `ABBB` are forbidden.

Example solution on the restricted alphabet {A, B, C, D} ($N=4$), with words of length 4:

`ABAB`, `ABCB`, `ABDB`, `ACAB`, `ACDB`, `ADAB`, and `ADCB`.

So 7 different paths.

- For $L=5$, the solution is 20.
- For $L=6$, the solution is 61.
- For $L=7$, the solution is 181.

I actually have a working program that can generate all those paths. The issue is that I want to know the exact length of the iterator without actually needed to consume it.

**Is-there a closed form solution to this?** I don't mind having to check if $N_A = N_B$, as long as I actually don't need to count each path iteratively.

Thanks for your help!

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I could not find any similar topic on the Internet, and I lost quite too much time on this to not ask for some help ^^'.

Answer (score 1):

Fix an alphabet size $m$ and assume A $\ne$ B. Let the number of such words of length $n$ be $f(n)$. Consider the second letter C, which must be different from A. If moreover C $\ne$ B then there are $f(n-1)$ many words of length starting with C and ending with B, and there are $m - 2$ choices of such C. Otherwise C = B, and consider the third letter D, which must be different from C (and therefore automatically D $\ne$ B) so there are $f(n-2)$ words starting with each of the $m - 1$ choices of D. Adding up, $$f(n) = (m-2)f(n-1) + (m-1)f(n-2).$$

Since $m$ is fixed, this is a [linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients), which has standard solution techniques, eg using generating functions or matrix exponentiation. The associated characteristic polynomial is $x^2 - (m-2)x - (m-1)$, which has roots $-1$ and $m - 1$. Therefore $f(n)$ is of the form $P (m-1)^n + Q (-1)^n$ for some constants $P$ and $Q$. Using $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = 1$ we can solve for $P$ and $Q$, which gives us
$$f(n) = \frac{1}{m} [(m-1)^{n-1} - (-1)^{n-1}].$$

Let us also handle the case $g(n)$ of words of length $n$ with the same constraint but with A = B. Again considering the second letter,
$$g(n) = (m-1) f(n-1) = \frac{m-1}{m}[(m-1)^{n-2} - (-1)^{n-2}].$$

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! This works like a charm and passes all my tests :D